# Conversation mining processing

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to scrape some data from a website in order to proceed to a lexical analysis. I'm pretty new to data mining with R and I've been using it only for college-related issues so sorry for being a bit nooby.
I'm trying to scrape text from a website as mentioned. To do so, I used the following command:

```
scraping_jst <- read_html(url)
p_text <- scraping_jst %>%
html_nodes("p") %>%
text <- html_text()
```

So I have now all the paragraphs in the text object. As most of these documents are dialogues I would like to keep only the lines that are from a certain person. Example :

- Alice: Hello
- Paul: How are you doing ?

I would like to find a way to select and extract only Paul's part (for example). I've tried to use the *strsplit()* function like this :

```
 test <- strsplit(p_text, ":")
```

But I'm a bit lost with the results...

Can someone help me ?

Comment: answer probably depends on what your call your "text object". can you show it or give the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to break down each line of text. Once you have each line where people said things, with their name in the beginning, you can use

`str_extract(a, "(?<=Paul: ).*")`

To extract everything after `"Paul: "` in each of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text input is an array containing strings formatted as in your example

```
text_array <- c(
  "Alice: Hello",
  "Paul: How are you doing ?",
  "Alice: Good, you ?",
  "Paul: Awesome: thx"
)
speaker <- "Paul"

parsed_lines <- sapply(text_array,
      function(txt){
        delimiter_pos <- regexpr(":",txt)[[1]] # returns the position of first semi column, you may have to deal with exceptions, like chapter names and other irregular lines
        speaker <-substr(txt,1,delimiter_pos-1) # text before delimiter
        speaker_line <- substr(txt,delimiter_pos+1,nchar(txt)) # text after delimiter
        return(list(speaker,speaker_line))
        })

parsed_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(parsed_lines),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE,dimnames=list(NULL,c("speaker","speaker_line")))) # reformat as a 2 columns data.frame, as parsed_lines was a list

parsed_df
#   speaker         speaker_line
# 1   Alice                Hello
# 2    Paul  How are you doing ?
# 3   Alice          Good, you ?
# 4    Paul         Awesome: thx

# Paul's lines
subset(parsed_df,speaker == "Paul")
```